My impulse reponse cancels out a sound
I am mixing a song and there is a double tracked guitar recording. When I load up an impulse response on both of them, one seems to cancel out and goes completely silent while the other is track is fine. I've tried different impulses on the track that goes silent and also inverting the polarity before it goes into the IR loader but nothing seems to work. Not sure what's going on here because I've never seen an impulse response make a track go silent before.

This is going to be a problem with your IR loader (which you don't identify).  I would contact their user support and be prepared to send them the IR which causes the muted output.
